# Extracting Frequency Data from Sorted List of Phrases

Tags: text, wolfram-mathematica

After plumbing the documentation/past questions on list operations, I've come up blank - many of the cases involve numbers, whereas I'm working with large quantities of text.

I have a sorted list of common three-word phrases (trigrams) that appear in a large body of textual information, generated through Mathematica's Partition[], Tally[], and Sort[] commands. An example of the sort of data that I'm operating on (I have hundreds of these files):

> {{{wa, wa, wa}, 66}, {{i, love, you}, 62}, {{la, la, la}, 50}, {{meaning, of, life}, 42}, {on, come, on}, 40}, {{come, on, come}, 40}, {{yeah, yeah, yeah}, 38}, {{no, no, no}, 36}, {{we, re, gonna}, 36}, {{you, love, me}, 35}, {{in, love, with}, 32}, {{the, way, you}, 30}, {{i, want, to}, 30}, {{back, to, me}, 29}, <<38211>>, {{of, an, xke}, 1}}

I'm hoping to search this file so that if the input is "meaning, of, life" it will return "42." I feel like I must be overlooking something obvious but after tinkering around I've hit a brick wall here. Mathematica is number heavy in its documentation, which is.. well, unsurprising.

Comment: `f[{"meaning", "of", "life"]` should should return `almost but not quite completely unlike 42`

Comment: @belisarius: Nope... the modern oracle says that it's definitely [42](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=the+meaning+of+life).

Comment: @Simon [Not entirely disagree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Not_entirely_unlike)

Comment: @ian For some interesting word statistics alternatives, see the Help for `WordData[]` and `DictionaryLookup[]`

Comment: Wolfram Alpha is [pretty unequivocal](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=meaning+of+life).. and it couldn't possibly ever be wrong, could it?

Comment: @belisarius Thanks! I've been really impressed with the power behind WordData[] - I just keep finding more and more in Mathematica.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you can load your data into Mathematica in the form you outlined, one very simple thing to do is to create a hash-table, where your trigrams will be the (compound) keys. Here is your sample (the part of it that you gave):

```
trigrams = {{{"wa", "wa", "wa"}, 66}, {{"i", "love", "you"}, 62}, 
 {{"la", "la", "la"}, 50}, {{"meaning", "of", "life"}, 42}, 
 {{"on", "come", "on"}, 40}, {{"come", "on", "come"}, 40}, 
 {{"yeah", "yeah", "yeah"}, 38}, {{"no", "no", "no"}, 36}, 
 {{"we", "re", "gonna"}, 36}, {{"you", "love", "me"}, 35}, 
 {{"in", "love", "with"}, 32}, {{"the", "way", "you"}, 30}, 
 {{"i", "want", "to"}, 30}, {{"back", "to", "me"}, 29}, 
 {{"of", "an", "xke"}, 1}};
```

Here is one possible way to create a hash-table:

```
Clear[trigramHash];
(trigramHash[Sequence @@ #1] = #2) & @@@ trigrams;
```

Now, we use it like

```
In[16]:= trigramHash["meaning","of","life"]
Out[16]= 42
```

This approach will be beneficial if you perform many searches, of course.

**EDIT**

If you have many files and want to search them efficiently in Mathematica, one thing you could do is to use the above hashing mechanism to convert all your files to `.mx` binary Mathematica files. These files are optimized for fast loading, and serve as a persistence mechanism for definitions you want to store. Here is how it may work:

```
In[20]:= DumpSave["C:\\Temp\\trigrams.mx",trigramHash]
Out[20]= {trigramHash}

In[21]:= Quit[]

In[1]:= Get["C:\\Temp\\trigrams.mx"]
In[2]:= trigramHash["meaning","of","life"]
Out[2]= 42
```

You use `DumpSave` to create an `.mx` file. So, the suggested procedure is to load your data into Mathematica, file by file, create hashes (you could use `SubValues` to index a particular hash-table with an index of your file), and then save those definitions into `.mx` files. In this way, you get fast load and fast search, and you have a freedom to decide which part of your data to keep loaded into Mathematica at any given time (pretty much without a performance hit, normally associated with file loading).

Comment: Great - I'll have to give the .mx process a try as the dataset grows and the processing times begin to creep up. Thanks very much for your insightful help for both the original question and these overall issues.

Comment: @ian.milligan Glad I could help, and thanks for the accept. I was playing with words and phrases and their statistics in Mathematica myself, a while ago.  Hope to get back to it one day. One other mechanism which you may find useful for these activities is tagging provided by `Reap` and `Sow` functions. It is general, efficient, and plays well with functional programming in mma.

Comment: @Leonid I think you may enjoy answering questions like this one http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42480/words-with-most-meanings/42496#42496

Comment: @LeonidShifrin My pleasure. Thanks for the Reap/Sow suggestions, I'll start exploring the documentation and examples.

Comment: @belisarius Indeed. But, may be I'll be better off by answering some of my own questions, which have been waiting for way too long already :).

Answer (score 5):

This is probably not as fast as the solution that Leonid gave, but you could just turn your list of pairs into a list of rules.

```
In[1]:= trigrams = {{{"wa", "wa", "wa"}, 66}, {{"i", "love", "you"}, 
    62}, {{"la", "la", "la"}, 50}, {{"meaning", "of", "life"}, 
    42}, {{"on", "come", "on"}, 40}, {{"come", "on", "come"}, 
    40}, {{"yeah", "yeah", "yeah"}, 38}, {{"no", "no", "no"}, 
    36}, {{"we", "re", "gonna"}, 36}, {{"you", "love", "me"}, 
    35}, {{"in", "love", "with"}, 32}, {{"the", "way", "you"}, 
    30}, {{"i", "want", "to"}, 30}, {{"back", "to", "me"}, 
    29}, {{"of", "an", "xke"}, 1}};

In[2]:= trigramRules = Rule @@@ trigrams;
```

Which (if you want) you can wrap up in a function that has a similar behaviour to Leonid's

```
In[3]:= trigram[seq__String] := {seq} /. trigramRules

In[4]:= trigram["meaning", "of", "life"]

Out[4]= 42
```

---

Since you have a very large list of pairs, then the application of the generated rules can be sped up by using [`Dispatch`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Dispatch.html). That is, do everything else the same as above, except define `trigramRules` using

```
trigramRules = Dispatch[Rule @@@ trigrams]
```

Comment: @Leonid - I'm sure that you didn't have the `Dispatch` part in your answer a couple minutes ago... Now my "hard work" is redundant!

Comment: Yes, you are right. It came to my mind right after I typed in my answer, and I put it there. It was probably within the single edit quantum of SO, that's why it is not shown as edit. To make it a fair game, I removed that part from my answer. Just be sure to edit yours to include `Dispatch` - or this method will be unusable for large files. +1.

Comment: These answers are all great - great approach to the question. My sincerest thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This is one way to get the individual words in your string into a list.

```
In[262]:= str = "meaning, of, life"; ReadList[
 StringToStream[str], Word, WordSeparators -> {",", " "}]

Out[262]= {"meaning", "of", "life"}
```

You could use this in a Cases or other form of look-up to get the 42 result (very suspicious, that figure...)

--- edit---

By "look-up" I have in mind the sort of mechanism shown by Leonid Shifrin. I was uncertain as to whether the difficulty being encountered was that, or simply converting from strings to lists of triads. I (only) show a way to manage the latter.

--- end edit ---

--- edit 2 ---

A comment shows ways to avoid ReadList. Let me state for the record that I'm ecstatic I managed to find that approach. Below is the code I had put into my original response, then replaced when I realized there was a more concise code.

```
str = "meaning, of, life";
commaposns = StringPosition[str, ", "];
substrposns = 
  Partition[
   Join[{1}, 
    Riffle[commaposns[[All, 1]] - 1, commaposns[[All, 2]] + 1], {-1}],
    2];
substrs = Map[StringTake[str, #] &, substrposns]

Out[259]= {"meaning", "of", "life"}
```

Bottom line (almost literally): I can find convoluted approaches as well as anyone else, and better than most.

--- end edit ---

Daniel Lichtblau

Comment: +1 I missed that part of the question. I find that something like `DeleteCases[StringSplit[str, {" ", ","}], ""]` is marginally faster. Or if you can guarantee the input structure, `StringSplit["meaning, of, life", {", "}]`.  Not that this is the limiting part of the search procedure...

Comment: I also missed that part - +1.

Comment: Great - this is a really handy command. My sincerest thanks again for your help.

Comment: The code in that 2nd edit makes my head hurt. (I had to pull it apart to see exactly what it was doing)

Answer (score 1):

Quite an old question.. but now we have `Association`

```
lookup = Association[Rule @@@ trigrams];
lookup[{"come", "on", "come"}]
```

> 40

or even

```
lookup = Association[
   Rule[StringJoin@Riffle[#1, " "], #2] & @@@ trigrams]

lookup["meaning of life"]
```

> 42